# How to execute one stored procedure from another one and save result as CSV file

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, export-to-csv, sql-server-2014

I have stored procedure which brings me some data from joined tables.

Some times customers wants from us export of these data in CSV which easily can be managed with opening as excel file.

So I want to create another procedure which will call given stored procedure and save it is result as CSV file.

Comment: Please add the examples in your question, don't post them as an answer. Oh.. You're just answering your own question, right.

Comment: Sorry, I just asked question and answered it.

Answer (score 1):

Let start .

This is our first stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[stpCOUNTRIES]

AS

BEGIN  
    BEGIN TRY 
        SELECT  NAMES,CODES FROM COUNTRIES 

    END TRY

    -- ---------------------------------
    -- ERROR HANDLING
    -- ---------------------------------
    BEGIN CATCH
        Declare @ErrMsg   nvarchar(200) = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
                @ErrLine  int = ERROR_LINE(),
                @ErrNum   int = ERROR_NUMBER(),
                @ErrSev   int = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
                @ErrState int = ERROR_STATE(),
                @ErrProc  sysname = ERROR_PROCEDURE();
        RAISERROR('ERROR in [%s] Line %d, ErrNo %d, Message: %s', @ErrSev, @ErrState, @ErrProc, @ErrLine, @ErrNum, @ErrMsg);
        RETURN @ErrNum;
   END CATCH
   RETURN 0;
END
```

And now I want to create another stored procedure which will execute first one and save it is result in CSV

So this one is our second stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[stpEXPORT_COUNTRIES]
AS

BEGIN  
    BEGIN TRY 

     DECLARE @FileName AS NVARCHAR(50)='PutFileName.CSV';
     DECLARE @Path AS NVARCHAR(50)=' C:\\PutPathWhereYouWantToSaveFile';

     declare @sql varchar(8000)select @sql = 'bcp "EXEC YourDatabaseName.dbo.stpCOUNTRIES" queryout '+@Path+@FileName+' /w /t, -T -S' + @@servername 
     exec master..xp_cmdshell @sql

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        Declare @ErrMsg   nvarchar(200) = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
                @ErrLine  int = ERROR_LINE(),
                @ErrNum   int = ERROR_NUMBER(),
                @ErrSev   int = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
                @ErrState int = ERROR_STATE(),
                @ErrProc  sysname = ERROR_PROCEDURE();
        RAISERROR('ERROR in [%s] Line %d, ErrNo %d, Message: %s', @ErrSev, @ErrState, @ErrProc, @ErrLine, @ErrNum, @ErrMsg);
        RETURN @ErrNum;
   END CATCH
   RETURN 0;
END
```

***Encoding of CSV fie is UTF8**